# How to fix issues with #pragma disabling warnings that aren't getting correctly popped

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, pragma

I'm currently having an issue using a third party library that has broken pragmas that are pushing a lot of disabled warnings without correctly popping them so they stay disabled forever. I want the warnings to be enabled in order to detect any problems in my code that is including the third party files. Since modifying the third party source should be a last resort I'd like to know if there are any other options to fix this.

The only thing I can think of is to manually add `#pragma warning (pop)` calls until the warnings start showing up again, but that seems really dirty. Is there some easy way to just pop everything that has been pushed all at once with a single call or something? If that's not an option, are there any other solutions to this problem other than trying to figure out how to fix the broken pragmas in the third party source? The third party source is very complicated so fixing it there wouldn't be easy.

EDIT: It seems like there's no real solution for this other than fixing the third party code so I guess I'll just work with the dirty solution of adding a bunch of `#pragma warning (pop)` statements in the files being worked on to make sure the warnings are enabled. It sucks, a lot, but I don't have the time to fix the third party code so it'll have to do for now...I'll leave this open for a couple days and if no better solution comes up then I'll close it out somehow.

Comment: So long as they don't push or pop warnings, and simply disable/enable them instead, you can fencepost their header with your own push/pop pair. And I advise if you do this to put it in your pch (usually `stdafx.h`) around their header

Comment: They are doing a `#pragma warning (push)` then disabling a bunch of warnings. There is a `#pragma warning (pop)` elsewhere in the code but it seems to be bugged so that it doesn't match correctly, which is why the warnings aren't getting reset propertly.

Comment: Egads. Those bastards. The solution is unfortunately not afforded by MS, namely a  `#pragma warning(push,label)` and `#pragma warning (pop,label)` unwinder. Some compilers do it, alas MS chose the road easily-taken. Totally up-voting this and watching it for a solution, as I'm sure you're not the only one that ran into this fiasco. if I run across a dupe/solution, i'll link it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only solution to this problem is to either fix the bug in the third party code or to manually add `#pragma warning(pop)` multiple times after including the third party files until the warnings start showing up. For me, I had to add that line four times.

Both of these options suck but so far there's no other way around it.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx) correctly, you should be able to do:

```
#pragma warning( push )

#include "offending_lib.h"

#pragma warning( pop )
```

Comment: No, that will not work if "offending_lib.h" does `#pragma warning( push )` and forgets `#pragma warning( pop ) `.

Comment: @AlexTelishev then add another `pop` manually after the `#include`.

Comment: The problem is that in different versions of a library you may need to add different amount of pops. And then code becomes a mess.

Comment: @AlexTelishev I find it unlikely  they're pushing without popping (and distressing if they are), only because doing one at least implies knowledge of the need to do the other. While I concur a solution such as this answer (which I also commented on) would not "solve" that problem, its the most minimal effort required to at least have a chance of success. honestly a push with labeling support and popping back to that label would be the silver bullet, but alas MS gave us no such flexibility. Edit: and the OP just informed us that is *exactly* what they're doing, so huh-boy, what a mess already.

Comment: @WhozCraig Unfortunately, I've run into this exact problem several times, and the problem was that under msvc 2008 and msvc 2010 there was a need to insert different amount of pops(. Of course, the problem is solvable, but it's such a pain to deal with.

Comment: This is a good option if it doesn't have mismatched pushes and pops so I'll give it a +1 just for that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to write a wrapper to that 3rd party library, so that only the warpper suffer from muted warnings.

As a side effect, you also benefit by minimizing risk when the library changes, or even when you decide to switch to other library.

Anyway, if you  are using VC you may reset warning behaviour with:

```
#pragma warning(default)
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx

Comment: This is bad, because you may have changed your warning levels in a compiler options, and after `pragma warning(default)` compiler will forget everything about those options.

Comment: That's why I suggested to warp the library first. resetting warning is only a quick & dirty workaround. BTW I also enable every possible warning (-Wall -Wextra and a lot more) for my projects, I like to turn on all of them, so the OP may as well force reset the warning states to ON.

Comment: I can't get this to work. It seems like you have to manually specify all of the warnings you want to reset to default; it won't just reset everything. So it has to be something like `#pragma warning(default : 4100 4365 etc.)`

Comment: @Calvin It's practically impossible to wrap a large library like Qt, and some versions of it have this problem.